# MS excel 2016 formula for booking calendar

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have sheet with calendar, where row (B5-H5) is day of the month and column (A6-A11) is room number. I want to see names of People that has reservation that day and for that room number in each cell.
Reservation details are in Reservation table on another sheet.

This formula returns #N/A even though there should be row that matches:

```
=INDEX(Reservation[NAME AND SURNAME]; MATCH(1; (Reservation[ROOM]=A6)*(Reservation[DATE ARRIVAL]<=DATE(MoYear;MoMonthNum;B5))*(Reservation[DATE DEPARTURE]>=DATE(MoYear;MoMonthNum;B5)); 0))
```

`DATE(MoYear;MoMonthNum;B5)` is a date from calendar in format DD.MM.YYYY
`Reservation[DATE *]` is a date in format DD.MM.YYYY
Cell A6 is a room number in format 'ROOM n.1'

Can anyone please tell me, where could be the problem with my formula?

Reservation table:

| NAME AND SURNAME | DATE ARRIVAL | DATE DEPARTURE | ROOM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Petr Vashek | 1.1.2024 | 2.1.2024 | Room n.1 |

Calendar (Peter Vashek should be in the cells, but its #N/A instead):

|  | 1.1.2024 | 2.1.2024 | 3.1.2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Room n.1 | Petr Vashek | Petr Vashek |  |
| Room n.2 |  |  |  |

I tried this following formula to get number of Reservation for each day and it works as it should:

```
=COUNTIFS(Reservation[DATE ARRIVAL]; "<="&DATE(MoYear;MoMonthNum;B5); Reservation[DATE DEPARTURE]; ">="&DATE(MoYear;MoMonthNum;B5))
```

Comment: A clear example, with data that can be copied, would help.

Comment: Reservation table:
NAME AND SURNAME DATE ARRIVAL  DATE DEPARTURE ROOM
Petr Vashek 01.01.2024 02.01.2024 ROOM n.1

Calendar table:
 Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
ROOM n.1       
ROOM n.2       
ROOM n.3       
ROOM n.4

Comment: Added to the original question, not dumped in a comment.

Comment: @SolarMike is it understandable now?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula works with this mod.

```
=INDEX(Reservation[NAME AND SURNAME]; MATCH(1; (Reservation[ROOM]=$A6)*(Reservation[DATE ARRIVAL]<=B$5)*(Reservation[DATE DEPARTURE]>=B$5); 0))
```

The cell B5 contains already a complete date.

One more restraint that the Reservation table must contains at least two lines to generate an array for the function MATCH.

Result

[image]

Comment: Still doesnt work. Maybe the problem is, that I have czech version of excel and the function MATCH() is translated to POZVYHLEDAT(). But even when I use POZVYHLEDAT(), it returns #N/A. I tried evaluate formula and go step by step. The error is in final step of evaluation: INDEX($A$2:$A$5;POZVYHLEDAT(1;1;0))=>INDEX($A$2:$A$5;#N/A).

Comment: #N/A is returned when there is no match.maybe that the lines are not the members of the table, or missing or wrong date format. The last step should look sg. like this: `POZVYHLEDAT(1;{1;1};0))`